# Как приложениям на C# общаться между собой?

Tags: c#, dll

Можно создать общую библиотеку для нескольких приложений и изменять переменные в библиотеке и что б другая программа получала данные?
Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: [Interprocess Communications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно [межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) (ссылку уже дал в комментариях Grundy).

Одним из самых простых и быстрых (если оставаться в рамках управляемого кода) способов является применение [именованных каналов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx) (named pipes).

Лично от себя я предлагаю попробовать технологию WCF. Используя её, можно легко переключаться с одного способа передачи на другой, меняя лишь привязки данных в конфиге и минимум кода.

Comment: ссылку можно продублировать и в ответе

Answer (score 0):

Можно наверное, вам надо будет использовать статичный класс и переменные.

Пример:

```
public static class Data
{
  public static string Name { get; set; }
  public static int Age { get; set; } //Авто свойства 
}
```

Однако рекомендую хранить нужную информацию в реестре или в файлах.

Comment: А вы проверяли? :)

Comment: Хмм, нет, но в теории должно (как и большинство вещей). Но я уже написал что лучше использовать файлы или реестр

Comment: Да как вообще это может работать, пусть и в теории - если у каждого процесса свое адресное пространство?

Comment: @"Pavel Mayorov" если статическое значение, то оно одно и все приложения,использующие библиотеку ссылаются в один участок памяти. (Но я пока ещё не проверял)

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы случаем не путаете экземплярные переменный с классовыми?

Comment: @RakzinRoman ничего подобного

Comment: @wardef нет, не путаю

Comment: @"Pavel Mayorov" ну значит я проверю и отпишусь. Значит при создании переменной в приложении я привяжу её по ссылке на значение из библиотеки....теоретически-так точно должно работать

Comment: @PavelMayorov тогда такой вопрос, вы проверяли что это НЕ работает?

Comment: @RakzinRoman а для чего вам именно такое решение? Если можно функционал написать в библиотеках а значения в реестре.

Comment: @RakzinRoman Каждый домен приложения, даже в рамках одного процесса, имеет свою собственную копию статических переменных.

Comment: @wardef Да, я проверял, Ваш код не работает.

Comment: @PetSerAl тогда приму к сведению, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь проект библиотеки в своем решении(Solution).

Затем в проектах этого Solution, которые должны использовать эту библиотеку указываешь ссылку(Reference). Слева выбираешь место, где находится библиотека, вроде Project in Solution.

Все, теперь твой проект связан с библиотекой в текущем решении. Изменяя либу, актуальные изменения будут в других проектах.